# Call a Asp.NET PageModel from a javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an Asp.NET web app and I am quite new to it. On the main page, in the Index.cshtml, I have an html table on which I would like do something when a user click on a row of the table. I have read on the handler, which seems easy to use on a button (you put it in a form ), but not trivial on any javascript callback... So, I have created my javascript callback in which a call the server. For an obscure reason, the GET request works fine, put not the POST request... Did I miss something? Maybe there is a better way to achieve this...
Here is the .cshtml file:

```
@page
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

@attribute [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

<h1>Journals</h1>

@if (Model.journals == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var journal in Model.journals)
            {
                <form method="post">
                <tr onclick="RazorFunction('test')">
                    <td>@journal.name</td>
                    <td>@journal.type.ToString()</td>
                </tr>
                </form>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function RazorFunction(msg) {
            fetch('?handler=Add&msg=' + encodeURIComponent(msg)); // This works and call the OnGetAdd function
            
            fetch('?handler=Add', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                body: 'msg=' + encodeURIComponent(msg),
            }); // This does not work and return an error status of 400.
            

        }

    </script>
}
```

And here is the Index.cshtml.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Security.Claims;
using WebApplication1.Model.Data;
using WebApplication1.Service;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly JournalService journalService;

        public List<JournalMembership> journals;

        public IndexModel(JournalService journalService)
        {
            this.journalService = journalService;
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            int user_id = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.UserData).Value);
            journals = await journalService.getJournalMembershipsAsync(user_id);

        }

        public void OnGetAdd(string msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnGetAdd!!!!!! : " + msg);
        }

        public void OnPostAdd([FromBody] string msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnPostAdd!!!!!! : " + msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The server probably expects an anti-forgery token, also known as CSRF token. You can read up on it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0 ASP.Net will automatically add a hidden input with this token to form elements, but you’re not submitting your form. Since your code is only a test, the problem may resolve itself once you change it to a complete form submission. For pure javascript requests you may also add the token as a request header. You can also disable the token check for the whole page using the [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] attrib.

Comment: I tested the code by adding `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` on top of `public class IndexModel` it works.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, it was the problem!